Question about affine hull
Let $(\mathcal{A}, V\vert_K, \varphi)$ an affine space and $M \subset \mathcal{A}$. It is true that
$$\operatorname{Af}(M)=\{\alpha P + (1-\alpha)Q : P,Q \in M, \alpha \in K\}?$$
 "$\supseteq$" is trivial from the definition of affine hull but I don't know how to show the converse.
If I take $P \in \operatorname{Af}(M)$ then there exits $P_1, \ldots, P_n \in M$ and $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n \in K$ such that $\sum_{i =1}^n \alpha_i = 1$ and $\sum_{i =1}^n\alpha_iP_i = P$. But I don't know how this help.
